Effect of ICC Profile Metadata of JPG images
I am using GThumb to assign tags to my images. Recently, I noticed that GThumb does not only alter the tags I manually change, but also deletes some tags that were set by the camera/phone, specifically, these:
ICC_Profile:ProfileCMMType            │                                                                          
ICC_Profile:ProfileVersion            │ 1024                                                                     
ICC_Profile:ProfileClass              │ mntr                                                                     
ICC_Profile:ColorSpaceData            │ RGB                                                                      
ICC_Profile:ProfileConnectionSpace    │ XYZ                                                                      
ICC_Profile:ProfileDateTime           │ 2022:08:08 08:08:08                                                      
ICC_Profile:ProfileFileSignature      │ acsp                                                                     
ICC_Profile:PrimaryPlatform           │                                                                          
ICC_Profile:CMMFlags                  │ 0                                                                        
ICC_Profile:DeviceManufacturer        │ XM                                                                       
ICC_Profile:DeviceModel               │                                                                          
ICC_Profile:DeviceAttributes          │ 0 0                                                                      
ICC_Profile:RenderingIntent           │ 0                                                                        
ICC_Profile:ConnectionSpaceIlluminant │ 0.9642 1 0.82491                                                         
ICC_Profile:ProfileCreator            │ appl                                                                     
ICC_Profile:ProfileID                 │ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0                                          
ICC_Profile:ProfileDescription        │ sRGB EOTF with DCI-P3 Color Gamut                                        
ICC_Profile:ProfileCopyright          │ Copyright Xiaomi Communications Co., Ltd. 2022                           
ICC_Profile:MediaWhitePoint           │ 0.96419 1 0.82489                                                        
ICC_Profile:RedMatrixColumn           │ 0.51512 0.2412 -0.00105                                                  
ICC_Profile:GreenMatrixColumn         │ 0.29198 0.69225 0.04189                                                  
ICC_Profile:BlueMatrixColumn          │ 0.1571 0.06657 0.78407                                                   
ICC_Profile:RedTRC                    │ (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)                         
ICC_Profile:ChromaticAdaptation       │ 1.04788 0.02292 -0.0502 0.02959 0.99048 -0.01706 -0.00923 0.01508 0.75168
ICC_Profile:BlueTRC                   │ (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)                         
ICC_Profile:GreenTRC                  │ (Binary data 32 bytes, use -b option to extract)                         

I used exiftool to print above table. The image matrix of the image was not changed by GThumb.
I am wondering, what is the effect of these tags? Do they have a noticable effect on how these pictures are displayed or are they just informational? If not, how can I avoid these tags to be deleted when I tag the images?

Manually comparing these two images reveals that the color scheme is slightly different.


I am wondering, what is the effect of these tags?

They specify the color space your camera used to create the images.
That means, this defines how the color values of pixels can be translated by a screen, or a printer, to the colors that you should be seeing.

Do they have a noticable effect on how these pictures are displayed or are they just informational?

yet, in your comment you write:

Manually comparing these two images reveals that the color scheme is slightly different.

Yes! They have perceptual effect! (and the fact that things are only slightly different is more or less luck; probably your display isn't very wide in color gamut, so both the "standard" RGB colorspace and the specified DCI-P3 color mapping work "well enough within the bounds of the screen's capabilities")
So, deleting them is deleting a lot of the relevant information about the picture.

If not, how can I avoid these tags to be deleted when I tag the images?

Fix this bug in gthumb, or use a different program.

I see, so this is kind of a serious issue, right? I noticed that the ICC information of all my pictures taken with my phone is the same. Is it safe to assume that this ICC information the same for each picture taken by the same device? In that case, I would just use exiftool to programmatically copy the ICC information from one picture into all other pictures taken by the same device (which can be automatically detected with EXIF tags).

Strange. I am trying to reproduce this issue in gthumb now, but now, it retains the embedded ICC profiles. Maybe, it isn't related to assigning tags with gthumb?
